# Rails 5 'nomethod' error during sign up

Tags: mysql, authentication, ruby-on-rails

I'm receiving the nomethod name error during user sign up. However, there isn't a name column in my users table in the database and there isn't a name field in the form so I don't understand why this error is being thrown. Here is the error and then my form, controller, and schema. [image: noMethodError in Users#Create (wtf?)]

```
  <%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :display_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :display_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and here is my users controllers. The error is originating from the users controller create action.

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And of course I thought it may have been the DB schema but it isn't. Here is the schema.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161109225217) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "display_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
  end

end
```

I have no idea what is causing this error. Any suggestions please!?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :password
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                      format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  end
```

And my user params -

```
private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :display_name, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Comment: Please add your `user_params` method.

Comment: And also add your `app/models/user.rb` file

Comment: Here is my model :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go and check your model you made mistake in validate field

your code

```
 validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }`
```

change to like this

```
 validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
```

Comment: thank you! wow, I couldn't figure out where "name" was coming from.. I spent over an hour searching my form, schema, etc. and must have overlooked it. Rails error wasn't very helpful either, but thank you so much!

Comment: If you feel happy for my answer can you put up vote?

Comment: I did! it isn't showing because I don't have a high enough reputation? I'm a newer user.

Answer (score 0):

You should not validate :name in your user model since you do not have the :name column in it.